I have an error that disappears when I set debug option in civicrm
I have drupal7 with CiviCRM 5.69.5
Since yesterday the contact dashboard for each contact is not working.
If I access /civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=1 or any other cid I get the following error inside the civicrm windows in drupal:

Errore
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

If I check in Chrome DevTools I see the following:

GET https:../civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=1 500 (Service unavailable (with message))

I also get the same error when saving after editing or creating new data for a contact (contributions, etc).
I am unsure why this happened, I was doing an update of a plugin and maybe something went wrong. I think I maybe had a DBError at some point, but then it completed. I must say that for once I was doing the extension upgrade without giving to much attention... lately there are never problems.
If you have clues on how to resolve (let me know what other info you need) thanks.
The strange thing is that when I activate debugging in CiviCRM the problem disappears and the contact dashboard works again!
Again does someone have any clues?

Check in the web server log for the error (e.g. apache, nginx).

When I load /civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=1 I don't see any errors in the apache2 logfile (with loglevel debug)

Anything in the civi log? What about if you turn backtrace on - it's in the same place as debugging - and then look at the response tab to the 500 error in the network tab?

Nothing shows up in the network tab of DevTools in Chrome when I activate backtrace.
In the civi logfile I only have this warning:
2024-09-11 11:00:24+0200  [warning] Deprecated function CRM_Contribute_BAO_Query::whereClauseSingle, use search by receive_date.
CRM_Core_Error::deprecatedFunctionWarning
CRM_Contribute_BAO_Query::whereClauseSingle
CRM_Contribute_BAO_Query::where
CRM_Core_Component::alterQuery
Array
(
[civi.tag] => deprecated
)

At the end, I restored the backup of the Civicrm DB from the previous day. Aftar restoring the DB, CiviCRM asked to update the DB for one extension (CiviRules 3.12) and this time I cheked the screen while he was doing it. The errors are gone and did not come back with the update.
